# Qt - circles for collision detection

Tags: c++, qt, collision-detection, qpainter

I've been working on a physics simulation with circles in Qt. Thus far the easiest way to define circles I found is to make a `QRect` object and then draw the ellipse with that rectangle as a "blueprint". Now I've just got the problem that it paints a circle but the hit box for the hit detection is still a square, which looks rather awkward. I've not been able to find a solution for it thus far and hope to find some help here.

```
QRectF Ball::boundingRect() const
{    
  return QRect(0,0,20,20);
}
void Ball::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    QRectF rec = boundingRect();
    QBrush Brush(Qt::gray);

    //basic Collision Detection

    if(scene()->collidingItems(this).isEmpty())
    {
        //no collision
        Brush.setColor(Qt::green);
    }
    else
    {
        //collision!!!!!
        Brush.setColor(Qt::red);

        //Set position
        DoCollision();
    }

    //painter->fillEllipse(rec,Brush);
    painter->drawEllipse(rec);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
QPainterPath QGraphicsItem::shape() const
```

> Returns the shape of this item as a QPainterPath in local coordinates.
>   The shape is used for many things, including collision detection, hit
>   tests, and for the QGraphicsScene::items() functions.
>
> **The default implementation calls boundingRect()** to return a simple
>   rectangular shape, but **subclasses can reimplement this function to
>   return a more accurate shape for non-rectangular items**.

For fine collision detection you have to use:

`bool QGraphicsItem::collidesWithItem(const QGraphicsItem * other, Qt::ItemSelectionMode mode = Qt::IntersectsItemShape) const`

which you can also reimplement, because checking for collision between circles is faster than checking painterpaths for intersection.

I haven't used that myself, but it seems like the function you use will only give you "coarse detection" so then you must manually check if any of those actually intersect with the fine grained method. This saves on performance, you use the rough check to isolate potential collision candidates, and then check only those items using the slower method. In your case it is not a convenience, because a circle collision test would be as fast, if not faster than the bounding box test, but that's how Qt is designed. Ideally, you should be able to pass your own collision detection function to `collidingItems()`.

Also last but not least, once you get the `collidingItems` list you can easily check for circle collisions on the spot, without using `shape()` and `collidesWithItem()`... It will actually save you some CPU time from not having to call extra virtual functions, plus the time to reimplement those...

So you can use something like this:

```
inline bool circCollide(QGraphicsItem * item, QList<QGraphicsItem *> items) {
    QPointF c1 = item->boundingRect().center();
    foreach (QGraphicsItem * t, items) {
        qreal distance = QLineF(c1, t->boundingRect().center()).length();
        qreal radii = (item->boundingRect().width() + t->boundingRect().width()) / 2;
        if ( distance <= radii ) return true; 
    }
    return false;
}
```

... and do it on the spot:

```
if (circCollide(this, collidingItems())) ... we have a collision
```

Comment: Allright I changed the code as following but it still seems to collide when it shouldn't. Anymore inputs?

void Ball::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
   // QRectF circ = boundingRect();
    QBrush Brush(Qt::gray);
    QPainterPath path0;
    path0.addPath(shape());

    //basic Collision Detection

    if(scene()->collidingItems(this).isEmpty())

    painter->drawPath(shape());

}


also is there a better way to come back to you than like this?

Comment: I do  that couldn't add it tough because of character limit. QPainterPath Ball::shape()
{
    QPainterPath path;
    path.addEllipse(boundingRect());
    return path;
}

void Ball::paint

Answer (score 2):

Read documentation! Just dig documentation of base class and its ancestors.
See [QGraphicsItem::contains](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#contains) and [shape](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#shape)

One more thing. There is a class [QGraphicsEllipseItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsellipseitem.html) so most of functionality you need should be covered there.