# Qt: How to implement barriers and collision detection in a Qt game

Tags: qt

I'm building a simple game that will have a character whose movement areas are restricted (ie. cannot walk through the walls and certain objects).  How can i implement this detection across a relatively large map without greatly slowing performance detecting for collisions with far away walls?

Furthermore, how can I draw or animate a map, identify where the "walls" or barriers are, and convert that information into a codeable form?

Comment: You should watch tutorials on how to create a game - And you should consider using a game engine. Qt is not designed for something like that

Comment: @Felix - actually Qt has some collision detection built in.

Comment: @ddriver Thanks! Nice to hear. I haven't worked with the Graphicsscene yet, but I guess I should try it out

Comment: @Felix - well, check the answer edit I made before rushing into it. It is really not the best tool, even if it has some handy functionality in it.

Comment: @ddriver I know QML and have worked with it, but thanks for the hint

Comment: @Felix I've made a couple in Qt already; I'm not making anything complex or serious, this is just a single off small project for fun.

Answer (score 2):

The Qt graphics scene/view/item stack already has some collision detection functionality built in, although it is fairly rudimentary. There are a few methods for the `QGraphicsItem` class:

```
collidesWithItem(const QGraphicsItem * other, Qt::ItemSelectionMode mode = Qt::IntersectsItemShape) const
collidesWithPath(const QPainterPath & path, Qt::ItemSelectionMode mode = Qt::IntersectsItemShape) const
collidingItems(Qt::ItemSelectionMode mode = Qt::IntersectsItemShape) const
```

I am not aware how this is implemented, but I think the map scene size is not that much of a factor as the number of collide-able objects.

There is also the `itemAt(pos)` method and the `items(rect,...)` for the scene, which can be used to determine if there is an object in the spot where you are about to move in, be that a point or a rectangular region. So you can easily get such items and check whether they will collide and how if they are moved on advance, based on properties like the direction and velocity of movement. This might be more useful to implement something more sophisticated and efficient than the graphics item methods.

Also, this might be useful when it comes to refining the collision detection:
[Qt - circles for collision detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942890/qt-circles-for-collision-detection/31943153#31943153)

That being said, graphics scene/view/item stack is rather clumsy and slow to work with, especially the implementation of custom elements and their drawing and animations and stuff. I'd recommend using QML - it will be easier to implement collision detection for QML and make a game, than make a game with the graphics stack. Furthermore, there are game engines available that work on top of QML (such as v-play) that may come with collision detection or even simple physics. The one big advantage if QML is rapid prototyping, it is a huge productivity boost compared to working with the C++ APIs and spend half of your time waiting for compilation. Also, QML graphics performance is better, and recently it even introduced a basic API for 3d graphics (and no, it ain't no unreal engine substitute).

Comment: Okay Thanks!  I've already built a couple simple games in Qt, but I've definitely noticed the poor graphics performance on intensive draws.  I've built in collision detection because I haven't needed it to be anything close to optimized.

Comment: I did some more research and am implementing a quadtree structure.  I would like to be able to generate an infinite map so I might look into a spacial hashmap, but I think i could also add a tesselating node expansion to the tree.

Comment: I'm checking out QML, because even though this is going to be more of a small demo of an idea than a fully fledged "game", that does interest me.